# Flutter Why Wrap doesn't work when surrounding rows?

Tags: flutter, row, flutter-layout

Im trying to wrap some content in flutter without success. 
I found i can't Wrap Rows like i do with Chips or Text widgets.
Anybody knows why?

These are three sets of Rows , each one with an Icon and a Text, that sits side by side. But in smaller screens it overflows, because there is not enough space (width).

I'd like that the last set of rows (one icon and a label) jumps to next line when the space in current line is over.

Thank you

I have tried to Wrap the Rows with Container, but didn't work.

```
    Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        Wrap(
        children: <Widget>[
            Row(
            children: <Widget>[
                Text('long text 1'),
                Text('an icon here'),
            ],
            ),
            Row(
            children: <Widget>[
                Text('Anoter Label'),
                Text('Anoter icon'),
            ],
            ),
        // I want this row to jump to next line when there is not space in 
        // current line 
        Row(
            children: <Widget>[
                Text('More Text'),
                Text('Moire icon'),
            ],
            ),
        ],
        )
    ],
    ),
```

[Flutter layout ok large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R7JC.png)

[Overflow on smaller screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYCss.png)

When i'm on smaller screens, the image with caption resizes and fits well. But the labels and icons above the image overflow. So id like that the last set of icon/ label the one with $ simbol e price, jumps to a new row. I can wrap when using only text widgets and it works, but then i loose the alignment i have on rows like mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround

Comment: Can you share design what you actually trying to do ?

Comment: why you wrap you `wrap` widget in `row` .? remove the topmost `row` & it will work fine.

Comment: Removing the topmost row didn't work. It works with chips or text. Not with rows.

Comment: I will add an image to show the layout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The width of the Row is determined by the `mainAxisSize` property. If
the `mainAxisSize` property is `MainAxisSize.max`, then the width of the
Row is the max width of the incoming constraints. If the `mainAxisSize`
property is `MainAxisSize.min`, then the width of the Row is the sum
of widths of the children subject to the incoming constraints.

To resolve your problem just set the `mainAxisSize` property to  `MainAxisSize.min` on your Row Widget

Answer (score 12):

Updated: this is somehow a solution

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.alarm),
              Text('60 Minutes'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.shop),
              Text('Lorem ipsumssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.attach_money),
              Text('Very expensive'),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

...

You can do this

```
Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('long text 1'),
                  Text('an icon here'),
                  Text('Anoter Label'),
                  Text('Anoter icon'),
                  // I want this row to jump to next line when there is not space in
                  // current line
                  Text('More Text'),
                  Text('Moire icon'),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

or this

```
 Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('long text 1'),
                      Text('an icon here'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Anoter Label'),
                      Text('Anoter icon'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  // I want this row to jump to next line when there is not space in
                  // current line
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('More Text'),
                      Text('Moire icon'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Wraping only text widgets works, but then i loose the alignment i have on rows like mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround

Comment: see the top updated of my answer, hope this will hep you

Comment: Thanks so much. Was looking for this behavior forever